# How to use urllib2 for calling a website?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I want to use urllib2 for opening a website, for example 'https://www.google.com/', but there is a error:

```
import urllib2
address = 'https://www.google.com/'
urllib2.urlopen(address)
```

Error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Could you help me? I can understand why I can't use urllib2, because if I use webbrowser.open(address), it runs well

Comment: Don't use `urllib2`. Use http://docs.python-requests.org/ It is much easier to use.

Comment: change it from https://... to just google.com and see if that works